# Comparing Column Object Values in Spark with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm writing methods in Scala that take in Column arguments and return a column. Within them, I'm looking to compare the value of the columns (ranging from integers to dates) using logic similar to the below, but have been encountering an error message.

The `lit()` is for example purposes only. In truth I'm passing columns from a `DataFrame.select()` into a method to do computation. I need to compare using those columns.

```
val test1 = lit(3)
val test2 = lit(4)

if (test1 > test2) { 
    print("tuff")
}
```

Error message.

```
Error : <console>:96: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: Boolean
       if (test1 > test2) {
```

What is the correct way to compare Column objects in Spark? The column [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#expr:org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression) lists the `>` operator as being valid for comparisons.

Edit: Here's a very contrived example of usage, assuming the columns passed into the function are dates that need to be compared for business reasons with a returned integer value that also has some business significance.

```
someDataFrame.select(
   $"SomeColumn", 
   computedColumn($"SomeColumn1", $"SomeColumn2").as("MyComputedColumn")
)
```

Where `computedColumn` would be

```
def computedColumn(col1 : Column, col2: Column) : Column = { 
      val returnCol : Column = lit(0)    
      if (col1 > col2) { 
         returnCol = lit(4)
      } 
}
```

Except in actually usage there is a lot more if/else logic that needs to happen in `computedColumn`, with the final result being a returned Column that will be added to the select's output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `when` to do a conditional comparison:

```scala
someDataFrame.select(
   $"SomeColumn", 
   when($"SomeColumn1" > $"SomeColumn2", 4).otherwise(0).as("MyComputedColumn")
)
```

If you prefer to write a function:

```
def computedColumn(col1 : Column, col2: Column) : Column = { 
    when(col1 > col2, 4).otherwise(0)
} 

someDataFrame.select(
   $"SomeColumn", 
   computedColumn($"SomeColumn1", $"SomeColumn2").as("MyComputedColumn")
)
```

Comment: This is certainly something I could implement, but is there truly no way to use traditional Scala if/else/else if logic on a Column object type? The logic I'm going to be implementing will get pretty robust (6-7 conditions) and I worry about the readability of the when/otherwise format going forward. I had thought about maybe doing Column.toString().toWhateverDataType but that seemed a bit hacky.

Comment: @Godwin if you're working with Spark, you need to get used to the Spark syntax. For me, using `when`/`otherwise` is much more readable than `if/else`, simply because I've got used to it. That's the way forward if you're going to work with big data and Spark.